# Does a windows store app need a ECCN to use the SkyDrive API?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store, onedrive, eccn

Does an app require a ECCN to use the SkyDrive API. The SkyDrive API uses uses a **https** URL. So, if I'm understanding what Microsoft says about **cryptography** in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh694069.aspx then a ECCN will be required because it is using a secure communication channel (SSL) and SSL is not listed in the unrestricted tasks where are:

- Password encryption
- Copy protection
- Authentication
- Digital rights management
- Using digital signatures

Can anyone tell me if I'm interpreting this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `LiveSDK` to use SkyDrive?

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Live-SDK-Windows-Developer-8ad35141) is a sample application that uses SkyDrive

Comment: I don't think it matters whether the SDK or the REST APIs are used according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/hh694069.aspx:

"When you answer this question, consider not only the code you wrote for your app, but also all the software libraries, utilities and operating system components that your app includes or links to."

Comment: @rip I found [Live SDK core concepts (Live Connect)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh826528.aspx) very helpful, hopefully you'll find answer to your question in this article